# jQuery not finding parent

Tags: jquery, parent-node

I'm trying to append something to a `fieldset` but ajax cannot find the parent of the button.

```
<fieldset id="asd">
        <legend>Export Model</legend>
       @Html.Label("Name") @Html.TextBox("name")
        <button onclick="addCategory()" type="button">Add Category</button>
    </fieldset>

function addCategory() {
            $(this).parent().append("test");
        }
```

I saw this example all over the site but it's not working for me. What did I miss?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your html like this:-

```
<button onclick="addCategory(this)" type="button">Add Category</button>
```

And then in function:-

```
  function addCategory(btn) {
        $(btn).parent().append("test");
  }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I guess it was missing the button reference